# Completely simultaneous execution of two instructions (RISCV)

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture, riscv

The question comes from a RISCV implementation, but I think it may also apply to many other architectures.

From a code with two completely independent instructions in sequence (generic ISA notation):

```
REG1 = REG2 + REG3
REG4 = REG5 + REG6
```

In a pipelined implementation, assuming there are no other hazards (simultaneous r/w access to the registers is possible and there are two independent adders), is it a violation of the ISA if the two instructions are executed completely in parallel?

In other words, at the same clock edge, can the 3 registers (REG1, REG4 and PC) be updated at once (PC+8 for the RISCV-32 example)?

Comment: Where's your problem?

Comment: At the level of the instruction set architecture, how would you even be able to tell whether this had happened or not?  If the architectural effects are as specified, the machine can internally do whatever it likes.

Comment: @NateEldredge At the ISA spec (v. 20191213) I have not found anything that would prohibit this "pc skip". The internal ISA state never passes by the intermediate state, but the final result is obviously the same.

Comment: No, clearly not, since real CPUs do this all the time.  (e.g. Intel since Haswell can run 4 independent `add` instructions per clock: https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/  https://uops.info/  https://agner.org/optimize/).  It only has to maintain the *illusion* of having run instructions one at a time.  The same concept as the C "as-if" rule applies.

Comment: How can you tell they ran in parallel?  Timing?  Timing is usually not part of the ISA specification, these days, for obvious reasons, as different processors of the same ISA will have different timings.  Other than timing I don't think there is a way to tell, so if it can't be detected or observed then how could it violate the ISA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, clearly there's no problem, since real CPUs do this all the time.  (e.g. Intel since Haswell can run 4 independent `add` instructions per clock: https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/  https://uops.info/  https://agner.org/optimize/).

**It only has to maintain the *illusion* of having run instructions one at a time,** following the ISA's sequential execution model.  The same concept as the C "as-if" rule applies.

If the ISA doesn't guarantee anything about timing, like that you can delay N clock cycles with N `nop` or other instructions, nothing stops a specific implementation from doing as much work as possible in a clock cycle.  (Some microcontrollers do have specific timing guarantees or specifications, so code *can* delay for N cycles with delay loops.  Or at least specific implementations of some ISAs have such guarantees.)

It's 100% normal for modern CPUs to average more than 1 instruction per clock, despite stalling sometimes on cache misses and branch mispredicts, so that clearly means fetching, decoding, and executing multiple instructions per clock cycle in other cycles.  See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) for some basics of superscalar in-order and out-of-order pipelines.

Comment: Thanks! *"If the ISA doesn't guarantee anything about timing"* Indeed, I've not found any specified guarantee. There is at least one visible difference for RISCV ISA regarding status registers (clock count), but that would not count as a **violation** of the ISA. For a Cortex-M0, e.g., there is no timing guarantee for the NOP but (if memory serves) the old 8051 does have it.